# DetailFragment with different EditText according with the args

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-components

What is the best clean way to for instance:

List - Detail

List: may have like 5 different types

Detail: I want to be just one, but perhaps is a bit complicated because each item needs different EditText

Example:

ListItem1 needs Name, Surname, Age so on DetailFragment I should only show these EditText

ListItem2 needs Url so on DetailFragment I should only show one EditText

ListItem3 needs 8 fields so on DetailFragment I should show 8 EditText

And so on ...

So, I thought to have a DetailListItemXFragment and on each Fragment have the stuff that the item needs, but if it grows I'll end up with N DetailFragment, but otherwise the logic for DetailFragment if I have only one will be huge.

So I want to know a proposal of a clean arch like creating a FactoryDetailFragment or something to make it scalable, any idea?

Comment: mmm... options could be create only one fragment with differents custom views and show only the necessary... but maybe is better to create differents fragments for differents details because are differents and your viewmodel or presenter it will be a mess.  So in my opinion, now seem the same screen but they are differents between them.  To decided the navigation, your presenter/viewmodel can decided it.

Comment: The list may increase so perhaps different fragment per item, right?

Comment: Yes, differents fragments per items... i don´t know all the roadmap, but if some screen changes, the others screens/presenters it won´t affected.  If you have commons logic between them, extract in another class like UseCases, extensions functions, etc

Comment: And do I have to create like a factory? instead of having if itemclicked == 1 -> DetailFragment1 and multiple if else I want to avoid this

Comment: If you use a viewpager2 component, only use a list of fragments

Comment: No, not viewPager2

Comment: Ok, i think is not necessary a factory here ... but is your choice.  And remember, if the first comment with the approach is useful for you, rate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you need different amount of fields, you could use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) in your DetailFragment for this. Each Item consists of a TextView description and an EditText field. You can always add different amounts of items to the RecyclerView.